# jaxb unmarshal returning empty list for xml with namespace and recursion

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal xml with namespace, but it is keep returning empty list for a Set

xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://profileConfig" xmlns="http://profileConfig"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Profile">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="metadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ProfileID" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Profile.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "metadata"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Profile")
public class Profile {

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    protected Metadata metadata;
}
```

MetaData.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "data"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "metadata")
public class MetaData {

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    protected Set<Data> data = new HashSet();
}
```

Data.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "data"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class Data {

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    protected String name = "";

    @XmlElement(required=false)
    protected Set<Data> data = new HashSet();
}
```

profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profile ProfileID="123456789" xmlns="http://profileConfig">
    <metadata>
        <data name="Type" value="A">
        <data name="Options">
            <data name="Option" value="option1" />
            <data name="Option" value="option2" />
        </data>
    <metadata>
</Profile>
```

I'm reading the xml file and unmarshalling into Profile object in java

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Profile.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Profile profile = (Profile) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("<PATH_TO_XML_FILE>"));
```

The Profile's getMetaData() returns empty list object without any exceptions or errors
I am not sure where exactly I made an error.

If I remove the namespace from the xml, it works as expected. By just using

```
<Profile ProfileID="123456789">...</Profile>
```

UPDATE
I have tried marshalling and I think there is something wrong with my namespace definition.

```
Profile profile = new Profile();
Data data = new Data();
data.setName("Type");
data.setValue("A");
MetaData metadata = new MetaData();
metadata.addData(data);
profile.setMetadata(metadata);

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Profile.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(employee, sw);
String xmlContent = sw.toString();
System.out.println(xmlContent);
```

output

```
<ns2:Profile xmlns:ns2="http://profileConfig">
    <ns2:metadata>
        <data name="Type" value="A"/>
    </ns2:metadata>
</ns2:Profile>
```

As you see,  element has no namespace attached to it, which makes sense to me because when I try to get metadata, I'm not getting null, rather a empty list

Comment: I think you have some mistakes in your example sources. In Profile you include Metadata (with lowercase d) and the Data.java also defines a MetaData object (with uppercase D). Maybe the issue is also related to this, that you use the wrong Metadata object in profile that match against the wrong element name

Comment: To **debug** JAXB, create an object with test data and *marshal* to XML. Compare that XML to the XML you're trying to *unmarshal*. That will tell you why the XML you have doesn't fit the `@Xml...` annotated classes you have.

Comment: *Curious:* Why did you add `required = false` to field `metadata`, when the XML Schema specifically says `minOccurs="1"`?

Comment: Do not use *raw* generic types. Change to `new HashSet<>()`

Comment: The reason it only works when you *"remove the namespace from the xml"*, is because the annotated classes don't specify any namespaces.

Comment: I have tried creating object with test data and marsaling to XML. the data element doesn't have namespace